# Google GeoChart with province map for germany

Tags: google-visualization

is it possible to use googles geoChart API with a map from a specific German province?
Create a map with this options works fine.

```
var options = {
          region: 'DE',
          resolution:'provinces',
        };
```

But if i try to use something like DE-BE instead of DE, the requested map does not exist. 
Is it only because i made a mistake or does the map definitely not exist?

Thanks
Robert

Comment: I did some experiments, and it seems like Germany does not have any province-level maps.  You can request additional maps by making a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no geoChart with province map for germany now.

But, as @asgallant says

> you can request additional maps by making a feature request.

As per experience with feature requests you should try **[vectorworkz.com](http://vectorworkz.com/)** where you will get the feature within a short period of time. VectorWorkz GeoChart can create a German province map for you that you can show in their GeoChart.